How can someone leave The Island on Lost?
In Lost season 5 episode 3 Jughead, John Locke asks Richard Alpert about leaving The Island and he answers by saying that it is a privileged information.

Locke: I expect you to tell me how to get off the Island.
Alpert: That's very privileged information. Why would I share it with you?

Was it revealed how Richard or even Jacob did leave multiple times in order to visit or interact with the survivors?

Two ways: slowly, then quickly.

There are two main ways of leaving the island under Jacob's rules†. Both are shown in S4E14, and are also shown, mentioned, or implied in others.
Travel in the correct direction
This is the method we probably see used most often. Simply sail or fly on the correct heading and you will be able to leave. The DHARMA sub was frequently used off-screen for this, and this was also the planned route for the freighter team and the Ajira survivors. The Oceanic Six did this in a helicopter.
Teleport using the Island's energy
This was the Man in Black's original plan, and the device he constructed to do so was used by Ben and Locke to move the island while teleporting themselves. Jacob could probably also do this via some other device or simply will, and possibly Richard too, given the timeframe of some of their trips.

† Under Mother's rules it's unclear whether there's any way to leave at all, and under Hurley's rules you can just leave in any normal physical way.
